# Stop parent function echo

Tags: php, oop, extending-classes

Let's say in PHP you have a class Parent:

```
<?php
class Parent {

    public function speak()
    {
        // Do bunch of stuff
        $output = outcomeOfAbove();
        echo $output;
    }

}
```

And you have a class Child:

```
<?php
class Child extends Parent{

    public function speak()
    {
        parent::speak();

        echo 'Hello from child';
    }

}
```

Now let's say that I want the content of $output in the Child speak() function, is there a way to capture the output of parent::speak(); and stop this function from echoing? Knowing that you can't change the 'Parent' class.

Comment: ob_* functions; but Child needs to extend Parent; and typically it's better for methods to return a value rather than echo a value

Comment: Yeah, forgot the extend part, updated it :) And also forget to add "knowing that you can't change the 'Parent' class."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP output buffering feature:

```
  public function speak()
  {
    ob_start();
    parent::speak();
    $parent_output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    echo 'Hello from child';
  }

}
```

For more info, see the [PHP.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

Good luck ;)

Comment: That did the trick! I knew it was something with ob_* functions, but I used `ob_get_flush();` Thanks!